# Compiling Java files with different filenames and class names

Tags: java

I am currently working on an online judge where users can upload submissions to programming problems in different languages. These submissions are then graded, and results are returned to the user.

I worked on C++ submissions till now, and allowed users to upload submissions, which would be stored as `submission_number.cpp` on the server (details of each submission are also stored in a MySQL database).

However, now that I am adding Java support to the judge, I can't compile the Java files on the server after renaming them due to Java's rule of having the same classname and filename for a public class defined in a file. Is there a workaround for this? I thought of modifying the user's submissions and changing the classname to the submission number, but this would create problems while displaying the users submissions on the website (users are able to see the full code for each submission) - more processing would be required to replace the submission number with the original class name, which would also have to be stored in the database.

Is there a way to compile without the filename == classname rule? Alternatively, can someone suggest a better workaround than the one I mentioned? Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need to rename your submissions? Can't you store the submissions in a folder called `submission_number` for each submission (or something like this)? Can you give the submitters a predefined classname before they actually submit their code? If you definitely need to rename them: do the classes of the submission have to be public?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to name the file different than the (public) class contained in the file. Rather than renaming the class I would name the file correctly. It could be very tricky to rename all references to the class name (could be even contained in a string). Maybe place it in a folder corresponding to the submission number.